# Does WAS Liberty support <system-property> and <resource-ref>

Tags: glassfish, websphere-liberty, system-properties

I just recently installed WAS Liberty 8.5.5.7 as I am doing a conversion to Liberty for a projected presently deployed and configured for a GlassFish 4 environment.

The glassfish project, has a number of  and  configured within its domain  configuration which the application utilizes to send out outgoing emails.

I was hoping the WAS Liberty supported such a configurations (system-property, resource-ref), can anyone clarify as I have not found any such documentation?

Answer (score 0):

To configure system properties for Liberty you would define a jvm.options file in the server directory (next to server.xml) and add the system properties like this:

```
-Dmy.system.propName=propValue
-Dmy.system.propName2=propValue2
```

each JVM option needs to be on a different line.

You configure resource references in the web.xml file, so I'm not quite sure what resource-reference in a glassfish domain does that is different from this.